# What is a Realistic score for a Shopify store on Google Page Insights for Mobile?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

What is an acceptable score on Page Insights for a Shopify ecommerce site on mobile?  Seems that nearly every one I enter scores low and in the red...

Answer (score 0):

Shopify as ready-to-use solution has got it's own limits and flaws, but some of the stores were able to achieve nice and good results.

When it comes to good examples:

[soworthlowing.com](https://shop.soworthloving.com):

Desktop - 96/100

Mobile- 57/100

[www.studioneat.com](https://www.studioneat.com/)

Desktop - 91/100

Mobile: 56/100

With little to no apps and responsive images you can achieve even better results on mobile

Comment: Unfortunately with Shopify it is nearly impossible to run a good store without apps.